# Overlaying a mask on top of an image (ImageMagick)

Tags: image, imagemagick, overlay

I'd like to place a [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxEls.png) over this [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gORJl.png) so that the result looks like this : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXVgH.png). I am willing to use a Python library or ImageMagick, whatever works.

I have read similar questions and tried to use the "convert -composite" command, to no avail. I am not very familiar with this field, I'd be very grateful for your help.

Best,
Jul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick,

Image:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Unix syntax

```
convert image.png \( mask.png -transparent white \) -compose over -composite result.png
```

or Windows syntax

```
convert image.png ( mask.png -transparent white ) -compose over -composite result.png
```

Result:

[image]